# How to encrypt to send request to CCAvenue payment gateway

Tags: integration, encryption

I am trying to send a request to CCAvenue payment gateway, but when I  encrypt the data and send them I am getting an error because of wrong encryption. I came to know that its bcz of wrong encryption from the CCAvenue team. They have provided me the working Key through which I am encrypting Using the AES256 Algorithm. Below is the code snippet, can anyone help me out with what is causing the wrong encryption.

I am sending the encrypted String in enc_request parameter to CCAvenue

When I am decrypting in apex I am getting the original string correctly,

```java
Blob secretKey = Blob.valueOf('working Key');              
Blob clearData = Blob.valueOf('vivek|INR|2|days|1.00|SMS|123456987|terms and condition|123456789|Pls call 022-2121212121 to pay your LegalEntity_Name bill # Invoice_ID for Invoice_Currency Invoice_Amount or pay online at Pay_Link.|xxxxx.xxxx@xxxx.com|test invoice mail|this invoice generate for testing|invoice.doc$77u/SGVsbG8gaW5kaWEK|'); 

//Blob clearData = Blob.valueOf('');    
Blob encryptedData = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES256', secretKey, clearData);    
Blob decryptedData = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES256', secretKey, encryptedData);   
System.debug(clearData.toString());    
System.debug('hexa '+EncodingUtil.convertToHex(encryptedData));         
System.debug('base 64->   '+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(encryptedData));    
System.debug(decryptedData.toString());
```

I used one more way of encrypting even That did not work

```java
Blob cryptoKey = Blob.valueOf('workingkey');

Blob hash = Crypto.generateDigest('MD5', cryptoKey );    

Blob data = Blob.valueOf('vivek|INR|2|days|1.00|SMS|123456987|terms and condition|9874563215|Pls call 022-2121212121 to pay your LegalEntity_Name bill # Invoice_ID for Invoice_Currency Invoice_Amount or pay online at Pay_Link.|xxxxx.xxxx@xxxx.com|test invoice mail|this invoice generate for testing|invoice.doc$77u/SGVsbG8gaW5kaWEK|');     

Blob encryptedData = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES256', cryptoKey , data);     
system.debug('encryptedData'+ encryptedData);     

String encRequest = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(encryptedData );    

String abc = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(encryptedData);    

system.debug('base64Encode '+ abc);
system.debug('encRequest '+ encRequest);
```

can anyone help me out with this,

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are they using salt/initialization vector?

Comment: @YsrShk they did not provide me any initilization vector.

Comment: Adding to my comments above, when I was decrypting, I was getting the string as vivek&#124;INR&#124; the original string I passed to encrypt is something of this kind vivek|INR| Can any one plzz tel me why this is happening in apex. I tried a lot but not able to figure that out

Comment: This is bcz salesforce automatically convert | (vertical bar) to hex code in debug. If you store the field on object level/field level you'll see as is.

Comment: Reason for salesforce conversion is - debug has also vertical bar, so to avoid confusion salesforce do the conversion.